# read file and store integer in index location

Tags: java, arrays

I'm pretty new to Java; how would I go about reading a file, then storing an integer in a certain index?

so here is the file:

```
17 15 27 7 19 4 29 101 22 29 14 6 14 89 22 47 28 28 29 69 2 27 28 18 7 10 19 90 13 55 18 96 5 7 6 32 26 51 25 65 29 54 14 79 4 17 5 59 20 6 0 55 5 38
```

and I want to read them as pairs to where the first number is the index, and the second number is the number to be stored in the index.

```
array[17] = 15
array[27] = 7
array[19] = 4
```

and so on until the file has no more integers to read

**UPDATE**

also, if it makes a difference, I have a 2D array to store it into

Comment: So read the text, split the line by the delimiter (`" "`), you now have an array, where the odd indices are the index for the target array and the even values are the value. You'll need to know upfront the maximum index of the target array so you don't get a `IndexOutOfBounds` exception

Comment: @MadProgrammer well, if it makes a difference, my array is a 2D array, and the maximum indexes are array[160][30] (I have filled it all with -1 and whatever I read in will replace the -1 values at that index, then I will print it if it doesn't have -1 in the index.

Comment: Well, you should add those details to your question, cause know I'm completely confused

Comment: @TheMarkofDom in case your array is a 2D array then you have to  provide i and j i.e input in form of 160 30 25 (25 is to be stored at arr[160][30])

Comment: @TheMarkofDom is case of 2D array, if you are providing only one value as location, then you needs to convert it to i and j by dividing it with no column to identify the row and remainder will be the column.

Answer (score 0):

First of all take input as string, and then split it in array using `string.split(" ")`. Then convert each value in array to corresponding integer value using `Integer.parseInt()`, lets name array as `A`. 
Create an array `B` of integers of size equals to (maximum value in array `A` at even position + 1). Ans then traverse the Array `A` again to set the values at corresponding position.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to achieve this.

One nice way which i always prefer is using the Properties class. Added a snippet to show how the class works. :) Let me know if you have questions.

```
    public void writeToProp(){
       Properties defaultProperties = new Properties();
       defaultProperties.setProperty("17", "15");
       defaultProperties.setProperty("27", "7");
       defaultProperties.setProperty("19", "4");
          try (FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(PATH_TO_SAVE_YOUR_FILE)) {
        defaultProperties.store(stream, null);
       stream.close();
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.toString();
       }
    }

    public Properties readFromProp(){
       Properties prop = new Properties();
       InputStream stream = null;
          try {
              stream = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_SAVE_YOUR_FILE);
              prop.load(stream);
       } catch (IOException ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
              if (stream != null) {
                 try {
                     stream.close();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
       }
    }

    public void getValue(String key,String value, Properties properties) {
           properties.setProperty(key, value);
    }

    public String setValue(String key, Properties properties) {
           return properties.getProperty(key);
    }
```

Comment: I honestly have no clue as to how this works, I have not learned it yet ._.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple snippet,

```
int array[] = new int[SIZE];
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {    
        String[] split = line.trim().split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i+1 < split.length; i++){
            array[Integer.parseInt(split[i])] = Integer.parseInt(split[i+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

For 2D array,

```
int array[][] = new int[SIZE][];
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
        String[] split = line.trim().split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i+2 < split.length; i++){
            int j = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
            int k = Integer.parseInt(split[i + 1]);
            int l = Integer.parseInt(split[i + 2]);
            array[j][k] = l;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use a scanner to read the file.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("nums.txt"));
```

Then run a while loop to run until the document has no more. Like:

```
public class ReadNums {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("nums.txt"));

     int[][] A = new int[160][30];

     while (sc.hasNext()) {
          String s = sc.readNext();
          String s2 = sc.readNext();
          int num1 = Integer.parseInt(s);
          int num2 = Integer.parseInt(s);
          A[num1][num2];
     }

     }
}
```